# NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this) returns null but NFC works

Tags: android, null, nfc

my app uses NFC reading on background and on foreground. For user info I use CountDownTimer(120 * 1000, 5 * 1000) in my activity and method onTick(long l) to check NFC status each 5 seconds. Sometimes (on Android 4.2.2, my client says, it never happend to me) NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(BaseActivity.this) returns null but background and foreground NFC reading still works! Turning off and on doesn't help. Re-install helps.

BG reading via manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.NfcReaderActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

FG reading via intent:

```
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter();
ndef.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
ndef.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

try {
    ndef.addDataType("*/*");
} catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
}

mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this.mActivity);
mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this.mActivity, 0,
        new Intent(this.mActivity, this.mActivity.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
        0
);
mNfcFilters = new IntentFilter[] {
        ndef
};
mNfcTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] {
        // White solid cards
        NfcA.class.getName()
} };

if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
    mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(
            mActivity,
            mNfcPendingIntent,
            mNfcFilters,
            mNfcTechLists
    );
}
```

It looks like NfcAdapter is stocked or freezed. Does anybody has the same experience? Where can be the problem?

---

After some testing I have new observations. This happen only after reboot. I though my app started twice and some thread deadlocks are present but it didn't. If I start CountDownTimer (called in onCreate method) with some delay (3 or more seconds) it works and getDefaultAdapter is NOT null. If starting delay is too low (2 or less secs) i found this message in logs: "E/NFC: could not retrieve NFC service" and then getDefaultAdapter returns null until I reinstall my app.

So short delay before executing CountDownTimer (maybe better will be Timer.schedule(..., delay, interval)) is temporary solution, but if somebody knows what is the best soluttion let me know.

Comment: How did you find out that `NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)` returns null? Where in your app are you calling the above code? Is `mActivity` the foreground activity when you call the code? Did you request the NFC permission?

Comment: I call getDefaultAdapter in mActivity in onTick method (CountDownTimer). There I set visibility to ImageView (gone if NFC is on, visible if NFC is off). Yes, mActivity is on foreground. I have NFC permission in manifest.

Comment: So the `if (mNfcAdapter != null) { mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch [...]` part is called immediately after `mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this.mActivity);` or are they called from different methods? Could it be that your activity is recreated at some point in between?

Comment: Both called in onCreate method. But NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this.mActivity); is called in CountDownTimer each 5 seconds and there returns null. Mabye it retursn null in onCreate too, I dont know.

I think foreground NFC reading stops working, getDefaultAdapter returns null, but background NFC reading works. Is it possible?

Comment: Then again: Are you sure that your activity is still running (i.e. is between the onResume() and onPause() lifecylce methods) at the time the timer callback executes? And that your activity was not recreated (possibly voiding the reference in mActivity) some time in between?

Comment: i have exact the same problem... Did you found the reason?

Comment: No but it appears after reboot on RugGear500. Others devices are ok. Maybe something wrong with lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was used on an emulator and on the emulator you can not do anything with NFC.