# NfcManager available but NfcAdapter is allways null

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I have a real device with NFC capability.
It comes with a pre-installed app to read and write RFID Tags and it works fine.
However when I try to use the NFC Api of Android, the `NfcAdapter` is always `null`

I verified the NFC capability by

```
Activity activity = getActivity();

PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
    //This one is returned
    Log.i(TAG, "Has NFC functionality");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Has No NFC functionality");
}
```

Also tested the Manager

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
if (manager != null) {
    //So the service is not null
    Log.i(TAG, "NFC  Manager working");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "No NFC  Manager working");
}
```

But when I use

```
 NfcAdapter nfc = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
```

it always returns `null`. The same happens when a context is used as parameter.

```
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context);
```

I used the CardReader example provided by Google and followed the NFC documentation to add more tests, so the permissions, intent-filters and technology-list are defined as the documentation says.

What am I missing?

My have left the manifest of the as it comes with the sample
Should I change something?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.cardreader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- NFC Reader Mode was added in API 19. -->
    <!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- NFC-related intent filter. Allows application to handle messages from any
                 NFC-A devices discovered. Other Android devices are required to support NFC-A.
                 See: res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: are you testing in a real device?

Comment: Get the test APK off the device and decompile it (see `apktook`). Look in the manifest to see if it's requesting and permissions that you are not.

Comment: @Jorgesys yes, it is told in the first line of the post

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I just used apktool and things are even worse, the manifest doesn't inclune any permission or intent-filter and yet that app is working. It comes with 2 .so libraries libdevapi.so and libfxjni.so and the clases are full of invalid and unreachable statments

Comment: Seems that app is using native libs. If that's the case then your code path is completely different than the sample app. Can you try on a different device?

Comment: Nonetheless, can you post your AndroidManifest here?

Comment: @Melquiades there you go, thanks.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman sorry, I only have that one whit NFC capability.

Comment: Did you try to give getNfcAdapter a proper context (mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(mContext))?

Comment: @corvairjo Yes. Also used that function but the result is the same.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman i loaded the .so libraries to my project, and defined the class that implements the native methods they seem to be providing, but the Ide says that it can't find the native methods associated.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660861/nfcadapter-getdefaultadapterthis-returns-null-but-nfc-works

Comment: @Melquiades Yes, i have tried to repeat the initialization in a period to see if the adapter is already available but didn't work.

Comment: I have now a related question. I forgot to mention that I'm working on Windows, I downloaded another example that uses the same .so libraries along with some .jar, But running the sample the .jar library throws an exception saying that the .so libraries are not found in /vendor/libs nor /system/libs. Should I change to a Linux distribution?

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved it, and as i suspected there is no nfc adapter available.

The device comes from a company that seems to assemble their own custom motherboard for the nfc device. The null adapter might be caused on purpose on the android compilation version.
After a lot of struggle I got the sample source of the pre-installed app and it comes with the native libraries and compiled jars, now I can handle the interface the right way.

I have found a lot of questions like this and some responses are not worthy at all , they keep leading to a posible wrong code usage even when the source is identical to the oficial android documentation and samples, so if anyone is still having the same problem you can follow this path.

1. Verify the availability of feature throught

```
PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
    //This one is returned
    Log.i(TAG, "Has NFC functionality");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Has No NFC functionality");
}
```

2. Verify the availability of the NfcManager

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
if (manager != null) {
    NfcAdapter nfc = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
    //So the service is not null
    Log.i(TAG, "NFC  Manager working");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "No NFC  Manager working");
}
```

3. Check for library/native implementation

If the steps avobe failed, use the sample apps to test if there is a custom adapter implementation.
Use [dex2jar][1] to get the source of the demos, check for the .so and .jar libraries used, and if there is a native code implementation.
Then you should if possible get the source code sample, i could not get the .jar required of the decompiled version.

Comment: I am running an instant app, the device has NFC functionality. Also, NfcManager is not null. However, when I call `manager.getDefaultAdapter()` it returns null. Log shows: `E/NFC: could not retrieve NFC service`.

Comment: I think devices come with NFC capability turned off for security reasons.
Check if you can enable the setting in "Connection preferences"
There are some possible fixes here https://techwiser.com/best-fixes-for-nfc-not-working-on-android/#4-Enable-NFC-in-Settings

Comment: it's enabled, it works with a basic app, but does not work with an instant app. I think instant apps do not support NFC